# What is the difference between creating a locale for en-US and en_US?

Tags: java, internationalization

I have all my `ResourceBundle` values in a table and formatted as per requirement. I have to change the languages on the website based on user selection in a dropdown at the top of the page.

If I use a language code such as `en_US`, then it works fine. If I use `en-US` as a language code, then it doesn't work. What might be the problem? Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"en" is the language code specified by ISO 639. while US is country code specified by 3166.
In Java, the Locale object recognizes the language as **languageCode_countryCode** (e.g. en_US) and not as **languageCode-countryCode**.

Comment: But there is no constructor for lang_country

Answer (score 49):

"en-US" is an [IETF language tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag). While Java'a [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class was clearly based on IETF language tags, it uses underscores in place of hyphens when separating language codes from country codes (and also variants), so calling `toString()` on the equivalent `Locale` will give you `en_US`.

As of Java 7 you can use [`Locale.forLanguageTag(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String)) and [`toLanguageTag()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()) to convert between language tags and `Locale` objects.

When converting strings to `Locale` objects it's a good idea to normalize by splitting components on hyphens and underscores, lowercasing the first component (the language code) and upper-casing the second component (the country code).

Comment: This answer is the best response for what to do in java code.   For other languages/frameworks, not so much.   When making calls between frameworks with different conventions, you have a "pratfall" of the coder needing to know a conversion is required. recommend using the convention of the framework you are calling from. When you are making calls to another framework, provide "proxies" that do the conversion. Why? it eliminates the need to know that the called framework uses a different convention. Contributors will ONLY "see" one convention using that one will avoid the pratfall.

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use 
`Locale us = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")` and `us.toLanguageTag()`, and that will do the conversion for you without having to create your own error-prone implementation.

Answer (score 4):

As of Java8, initializing the locale should be done using the language tag `en-US`. `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US").toString();` returns the output: `en_US`

Where as `Locale.forLanguageTag("en_US")` does not create the required locale. It will default to the system locale.
`Locale.forLanguageTag("en_US").toString()` returns `null`

Comment: What is the reason, toString() uses underscore _?  Inconsistency with language tag