# Which format of "en_US" and "en-US" should be used in Http header request as Accept-Language?

Tags: java, android, http-headers, http-accept-language

I actually tested these two formats and my server is okay with both. Since [Http header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) is saying "en-US" is the format and my Local java class is returning "en_US", I'm little bit confused to get which of them to use!

My partial code is like this:

```
// set accepted language
            List<String> acceptedLanguages = null;
            final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault(); // en
            if (defaultLocale != null)
            {
                final String defaultLang = defaultLocale.toString(); // en_US
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultLang))
                {
                    acceptedLanguages = new ArrayList<String>();
                    acceptedLanguages.add(defaultLang);

                    // Always add en as fallback if applicable
                    if (!HttpClient.DEFAULT_ACCEPTED_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY.equals(defaultLang))
                    {
                        acceptedLanguages.add(HttpClient.DEFAULT_ACCEPTED_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY);
                    }
                }
            }

            String header = HttpClient.getAcceptLanguageHeader(acceptedLanguages); // like: cz_CH;q=1.0, en_US;q=0.9
            this.mHttpGetRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, header);
```

`getAcceptLanguageHeader()` method adds `en_US;q=0.9`to the string if user's device language in not `en_US`.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe hyphen "-" is accepted as part of the HTTP standard, while underscore "_" will be rejected. See [W3C HTTP v1.1 Standard, Header Field Definitions, Section 14.4 Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more info.

Note: **W3C** stands for **World Wide Web Consortium**.

Answer (score 0):

**"en"** is the language code specified by `ISO 639`. while US is country code specified by 3166.
In Java, the Locale object recognizes the language as `languageCode_countryCode` (e.g. en_US) and not as `languageCode-countryCode`.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use) for more

Comment: Yup, I saw your answer before at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4632943/513413, but my question is related to Http header and what happens if "en_US" passes to backend instead if "us-US".