# Should I use _ (underscore) or - (dash) while using locale ID?

Tags: java, localization

Why does `java.util.Locale.US` show `en_US`? When we construct, why do we need to pass it as `en-US`?

What is the difference between these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between creating locale for en-US and en\_US?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632885/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-locale-for-en-us-and-en-us)

Comment: More answers here also: [en_US or en-US, which one should you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904803/en-us-or-en-us-which-one-should-you-use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see both versions quite often. However, [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) (which is part of the IETF BCP 47 document series) prescribes a hyphen as the separator character. [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) seems to allow both versions:

> Well-formed variant values have the form `SUBTAG (('_'|'-') SUBTAG)*` where `SUBTAG = [0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]{3} | [0-9a-zA-Z]{5,8}`. (Note: BCP 47 only uses hyphen ('-') as a delimiter, this is more lenient).